# Symfony2: Check if JSON value is in response and if it's TRUE in test

Tags: php, json, symfony, testing

I have read [Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) in Symfony2 book but did not find any useful to do this so, I'm creating test for controllers in my application and this is the controller (just relevant code) I'm trying to test:

```
public function createCompanyAction(Request $request) {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    try {
    if (statement) {
            // do the magic here
            $response["success"] = true;
        } else {
            $response['errors'] = "some error";
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response["exception"] = $ex->getMessage();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

The test will pass only if `$response` has TRUE value in `success` key but I don't know how to check that from my test controller. This is the code I have:

```
$client->request('POST', '/create-company', $data);
$response = $client->getResponse();

$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), 'HTTP code is not 200');
$this->assertTrue($response->headers->contains('Content-Type', 'application/json'), 'Invalid JSON response');

$this->assertNotEmpty($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

How I check this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I answer myself. Searching trough Google I found `JsonResponse` [tests](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Tests/JsonResponseTest.php) and I found how to test it, so I transform my code into this:

```
$client->request('POST', '/create-company', $data);

$response = $client->getResponse();
// Test if response is OK
$this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
// Test if Content-Type is valid application/json
$this->assertSame('application/json', $response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
// Test if company was inserted
$this->assertEquals('{"success":"true"}', $response->getContent());
// Test that response is not empty
$this->assertNotEmpty($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

I have not tested yet but it may works.

Comment: Better not to hard-code HTTP status codes. It makes the code less readable and maintainable over time. I suggest using constants for this purpose `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_OK`.

Comment: Or you can use `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());` instead of constants, whatever you prefer :)